# can't update computer inside chroot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, updates, chroot

I am repairing GRUB2.
I entered the old system from Live Usb using `chroot`. (As explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur/).) I tried to run `apt update` and it said it couldn't access any server. (At least it told my this for any single server, I can't give you the error message because it's german.)

I tried to `ping`:

```
root@xubuntu:/# ping google.de
ping: google.de: Name or Service unknown
```

(I translated the error message.)

I'm unsure what I'm missing. How to update my computer?

Comment: For English error messages, issue "LANG=C" in your shell.

Did you already try re-installing grub as mentioned in the wiki article? (ab 'chroot-Methode' abwärts). Usually there's no need to re-install (as in apt install) grub. That's what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I typed this and then retyped what I did. Error messages still german.

Answer (score 0):

You booted from a live USB stick to rescue your old install, you most likely have no network routes set up...

```
route -n
```

Will show you your active routes, you need to read your network configuration file and add the appropriate route in order to have access to the internet.
After you `chroot` your old FS, you may restart your network services and this will automatically load the network routes you have previously set up (at least on CentOS).
Also, it's possible you have no entries in your `resolv.conf`, so your server does not know who `google.com` is, you may use google's famous DNS server `8.8.8.8` for this purpose